# 2 passwords 1 account login

Tags: login

Is there a way of having more than 1 password for the same user account. At the login screen so that I could have an account,more than one person uses it but they have separate passwords

Comment: why not have two separate user accounts for two separate users?  you can put them in a group and use that to define common privileges and stuff.

Comment: I could do that but it would take a lot of time to do that and I just want one account with multiple passwords

Comment: No it not possible to have two different password for one account. In backend it would have username field and password field. Code will verify the user name first and then enters the loop for password authentication. It will match the password for respective user account and password field will be unique..

Comment: here is an working method using ldap: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90684/can-you-give-a-user-account-multiple-passwords and the bottom answer works for Linux+/etc/passwd http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/90947/10017 I pm'd Gilles to post here ;)

Comment: If they log in as the same account, then what would be the point in each having their own password?  The system treats them the same anyhow so they may as well just both know the same password.

Comment: @psusi true. I never claimed it is a good idea ;) If it is about permissions using 2 users with 1 group OR editing the sudoers file to match the 2 users to allow for the same permissions would be smarter.

Answer (score 1):

I don't realize why you need this, but maybe a second user whit the seame uid the first one could work. This way you can have 2 distinct usernames and password besides same permissions.